# KnockoutJS select lookup

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I am trying to bind a select with KnockoutJS to a predefined value that comes from my model. According to the documentation this should come from the *value* property but I am not able to preselect a value in the dropdown based on this. Here is sample code that reflects the issue that I have:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/knockout-2.0.0.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {

        var viewModel =
        {
            Positions: ko.observableArray(
                                            [
                                                { Id: 1, PositionName: 'Point Guard' },
                                                { Id: 2, PositionName: 'Shooting Guard' },
                                                { Id: 3, PositionName: 'Center' },
                                                { Id: 4, PositionName: 'Small Forward' },
                                                { Id: 5, PositionName: 'Power Forward' }
                                            ]),
            Players: ko.observableArray(
                                            [
                                                { Id: 1, Name: 'Derrick Fisher', Position: 'Point Guard' },
                                                { Id: 2, Name: 'Kobe Bryant', Position: 'Shooting Guard' },
                                                { Id: 3, Name: 'Andrew Bynum', Position: 'Center' },
                                                { Id: 4, Name: 'Metta World Peace', Position: 'Small Forward' },
                                                { Id: 5, Name: 'Pau Gasol', Position: 'Power Forward' }
                                            ])
        };

        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    });
</script>
```

In my bindings I would like to use a simple table where the first column has preselected the lookup value, in this case the "position" of the player by default. Here is an example:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Position</td>
            <td>Player</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody data-bind='foreach: Players'>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select data-bind="options: $root.Positions, optionsText:'PositionName', 
                                value:'$data.Position', optionsCaption: 'Choose...'">
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span data-bind='text: Name'></span>                                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The lookups seem to bind okay (the select is populated with all the position values in lookup) however the given player's position is not selected by default. Can anyone spot where I've made a bad assumption or error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do not use `optionsValue`, then it will write the selected object to what you have bound to `value`.

If your `player` has a separate copy of the `position` object, then it will not match.

For example,

```
var a = { Id: 3, Name: 'Andrew Bynum', Position: 'Center' };
var b = { Id: 3, Name: 'Andrew Bynum', Position: 'Center' };

alert(a === b); //false they are not a reference to the same object
```

So, your player's either need to use a reference to the same object or you should specify the `optionsValue` binding with `Id`, so that it reads/writes the Id to the player's position property.

Comment: Thank you for help! I was trying to go off example 4 at http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html but in this case you're right, just had to bind optionsValue

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown where $data.Position comes from.
You may need to set optionsValue as well, http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/options-binding.html

It lets you make the value binding to a property rather than a JS object.